# Can't copy .wav sounds from USB to SD card reader

Tags: 18.04, usb, sd-card

I want to copy .wav sounds from my SD reader to my USB drive but it doesn't seem to work.
It does work with Windows with the same devices and files.

Error code: Error opening file “/media/filessamplesfs/b471cde8-2a15-44e7-acce-e9a2a54511a6/padio/th06_01.wav”: Access Denied

Ubuntu version: 18.04

UPDATE: Stopped working on Windows. I tried it on another computer and the files were gone.

Comment: It could be a problem with ownership and permissions. See [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11840/how-do-i-use-chmod-on-an-ntfs-or-fat32-partition/956072#956072). Or it could be problems because the USB drive or the SD card is failing, or if you are lucky, there is 'only confusion'. See [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035).

Answer (score 0):

The drive may be failing if it no longer works on Ubuntu and Windows, or maybe its in read-only mode? If it's stuck in read-only mode that might be a setting in software or the physical drive, or its dying.

Answer (score 0):

If it's formatted `ntfs` you may need to install `ntfs-3g` before being able to read/write.

It could also be a permissions issue. Have a look at the output of:

`sudo blkid`

And:

`mount`

To find out where the mountpoint of your card is (in Ubuntu 18.04 it's often somewhere in `/media/<your-username>/something`). Then use `ls -la /media/your/mount/point` to look at who owns the folder and whether it's read-write to your user. It

Comment: The SD card reader has 3 partitions. One of them is ext4. The files cannot be copied on any partition.

The USB stick is formatted in NTFS. I have also tried copying the files to the SSD which worked and tried to move them on the SD card reader (ext4 partition). Still didn't work
(if you're wondering the usb drive is a kingston 32gb dt106 which I bought 2 months ago. the sd reader is a hama usb 2.0 reader 35 in 1. possibly bought over 10 years ago.)